# NoClassDefFoundError ans static vs instance level

Tags: java, static

Suppose if I run the below code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class NoClassDefFoundErrorDueToStaticInitFailure {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Main start");
        new User("1");
    }
}

class User {
    private static String USER_ID = getUserId();

    public User(String id) {
        this.USER_ID = id;
    }

    private static String getUserId() {
        throw new RuntimeException("UserId Not found");
    }

}
```

it gives

```
Main start
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.NoClassDefFoundError.NoClassDefFoundErrorDueToStaticInitFailure.main(NoClassDefFoundErrorDueToStaticInitFailure.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: UserId Not found
    at com.NoClassDefFoundError.User.getUserId(NoClassDefFoundErrorDueToStaticInitFailure.java:22)
    at com.NoClassDefFoundError.User.<clinit>(NoClassDefFoundErrorDueToStaticInitFailure.java:15)
    ... 1 more
```

---

But, If I remove static from the above User class and make it as below

```
class User {
    private String USER_ID = getUserId();

    public User(String id) {
        this.USER_ID = id;
    }

    private String getUserId() {
        throw new RuntimeException("UserId Not found");
    }
}
```

stack trace now is :

```
Main start
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: UserId Not found
    at com.NoClassDefFoundError.User.getUserId(NoClassDefFoundErrorDueToStaticInitFailure.java:22)
    at com.NoClassDefFoundError.User.<init>(NoClassDefFoundErrorDueToStaticInitFailure.java:15)
    at com.NoClassDefFoundError.NoClassDefFoundErrorDueToStaticInitFailure.main(NoClassDefFoundErrorDueToStaticInitFailure.java:10)
```

Not able to understand why this change happened because of removal of static(class level) keyword

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, when you reach the line

```
new User("1");
```

the `User` class is loaded and initialized, executing

```
private static String USER_ID = getUserId();
```

which fails with `ExceptionInInitializerError` because of the `RuntimeException` thrown in `getUserId()`. The `ExceptionInInitializerError` is thrown by the `ClassLoader`.

In the second example, you simply have an instance method that throws a `RuntimeException`. When you eventually call the method, it will bubble up to the JVM's uncaught exception handler and terminate the program.

---

Consider reading the Java Language Spec chapter for [When Initialization Occurs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1).